# FindBugs skipping various bugs

Tags: eclipse, findbugs

I've got findbugs in eclipse enabled with everything and at the lowest setting. It is only finding some of the bugs instead of all of them.

```
    String b = "bob";
    b.trim();
    b.replace('b', 'p');
```

In the above code, I thought findbugs should flag the issue of not using the return value (a case which plenty of other websites show findbugs detecting) but it doesn't flag this case.

I also figured it would find a null bug or possible out of bounds.

```
ArrayList<String> test=getList();
String c=test.get(10);

private ArrayList<String> getList() {
    return null;
}
```

Why aren't these being detected?

Comment: Do you have this rule active? http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#RV_RETURN_VALUE_IGNORED

Comment: I have RV:MethodReturnCheck and RV:BadUseOfReturn according to eclipse. Those are the only RV entries

Answer (score 0):

For the second issue, you must annotate the method `getList` with `@CheckForNull` so FB knows the method may return `null`.